# More efficient way to merge two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have to fill a certain column in the dataframe based some conditions and values from other dataframe. I want to merge df to df_damage_func with a certain 'ID' then I want to merge by having a look 'FloodMeters' and 'Damage EUR - Absolute' depending on the 'Class1' and I only want to merge when df['Sector'] == 'Automotive' & df['Class1'] == 'Class1' in df_damage_func

This is how I am doing it right now

```
df[col_name+'_Damage EUR - Absolute'] = np.nan
grouped = df_dam_func.groupby('Id')
x = grouped.get_group(2)
x_grp = x.groupby('Class1')
dic_2 = {}
for n, y in x_grp:
    dic_val = dict(zip(y['FloodMeters'], y['Damage EUR - Absolute']))
    dic_2[n] = dic_val
    
for k1,v1 in dic_2.items():
    for k2,v2 in v1.items():
        # print(k1,k2)
        df.loc[(df['Sector'] == 'Automotive') & (df['Class1'] == k1) & (round(df[col_name],1) == k2), col_name+'_Damage EUR - Absolute'] = v2
```

df is the main dataframe and df_dam_func is the one I am using to fill values, (code above is working correctly). I am doing it by first creating a dictionary for look up and then filling the values in the new column.

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this operation?
Thanks for the help

Comment: `grouped` is not defined in your example code. What is your input and your expected output? Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: just did that. Thank you for the comment

Comment: Now `df` , `col_name` and `df_dam_func` are not defined.

Comment: df and df_dam_func are read directly from the csv file and col_name is just a string, sorry for the confusion as this is my first questions here